# How do I sort a date field in views without the time?

Tags: views, datetime

Drupal 7

I have a view that sorts on three fields so the ORDER BY statement looks like:
ORDER BY

node_status ASC,
field_data_field_date_field_date_value DESC, field_data_field_sort_order_field_sort_order_value ASC

I need the sort of the date field to not be granular to the time. I just want it sorted by the date so that the sort order field will take it from there. When I run the query against the database itself, I see that the date field returned is showing the full value like: 2016-06-19 08:48:12, but some of the values are different by a second, causing the "incorrect" (not the desired) sort order.

How can I get it to sort on the date field (date field module) without the "full date" field?

EDIT:
(adding screen shot of view)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D7 only provides granularity for the core fields not added fields.

D8 provides granularity for the core and added fields.

I have added D7 functionality as a patch to the module [views_date_format_sql](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql). See [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql/issues/2016281#comment-13966009).

Views_date_format_sql can also do custom formats as well.

Note:

- The D8 patch is only for core date fields so far (e.g. node updated).

Answer (score 1):

you can change the granularity of the sort under the settings for the sort criteria:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the settings to click on to get that. I added a screen shot of my view to my question. I do have it for the filter on date.

Comment: If you're using the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) Module, you can set the granularity in the Field Settings for that particular field

Comment: It is a date field with the date module and the field is defined as only collecting month, day, and year. I wish I knew why I wasn't seeing what you see for those settings.

Comment: We have now done a work-around. We have rules applied when these items are published to set the date. It was getting set with "now" and I have changed it to "today" and it is just setting the field with the midnight time.

Comment: well, if it works... you aren't seeing what I posted because you didn't specify you were using the Date Field module, the image I posted is for core Post Date Field